# Passing reserved names as props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a ton of repetitive form inputs that I would like to abstract into a component. I would like to do the following:

```
<InputElement title="someTitle" v-model="someName" @blur="someFunction" name="someName" type="someType">
```

and have it spit out code like below

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>Your name</label>
    <input v-model="userame" @blur="validateNotEmpty" name="userame" type="text">
    <p style="color:red" v-if="errors.applicantName === false">Fail</p>

    <label>Phone Number</label>
    <input v-model="phoneNumber" @blur="validateNotEmpty" v-mask="'###-###-####'" name="phoneNumber" />
    <p style="color:red" v-if="errors.phoneNumber === false">Fail</p>

    <label>Your email</label>
    <input v-model="email" @blur="validateEmail" name="email" type="email">
    <p style="color:red" v-if="errors.email === false">Fail</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

I have created `InputElement.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>{{ inputTitle }}</label>
    <input v-model="v-model" @blur="@blur" name="name" type="type">
    <p style="color:red">Fail</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['inputTitle', 'v-model', '@blur', 'name', 'type']
}
</script>
```

And this obviously fails for so many reasons.

What is a simple solution in `Vue.js` for abstracting form inputs into components and passing reserved keywords as props?

Comment: Why is it necessary to use reserved words? It's bad practice

Comment: @Brennan Edited. I would like to be able to pass from the parent a value that would be assigned to e.g. v-model. How else would I achieve that without using reserved keywords ?

Comment: `v-bind` doesn't suit your needs? also I'd recommend using slots and mixins.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal care to show an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass v-model from the parent to child, simply use `value` as a prop and emit `input` event as shown in [VueJS documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events) :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>{{ inputTitle }}</label>
    <input v-model="myvalue" @blur="onblur" :name="name" :type="type">
    <p style="color:red">Fail</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['inputTitle', 'value', 'name', 'type'],
  computed : {
    myvalue : {
        set : function (newVal) {
            this.$emit('input',newVal);
        },
        get : function () {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
  },
  methods : {
    onblur : function (event) {
        this.$emit('blur',event);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and you use your component in the parent as such:

```
<InputElement :input-title="someTitle" v-model="someName" @blur="someFunction" :name="someName" :type="someType">
```

I haven't tested this code though.